# How to add a check box to an alert dialog

Tags: android, checkbox, android-alertdialog

Currently when the user opens my app, an `AlertDialog` opens, asking them if they would like to upgrade to the pro version.

I need to add a `CheckBox` to the `AlertDialog` that will make the app no longer show the `AlertDialog` when the user opens the app.

Here is what I have for the `AlertDialog` now:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(" MY_TEXT");
    builder.setMessage(" MY_TEXT ")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=MY_APP_PACKAGE");
                   Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                   startActivity(intent);                          }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           }).show();
```

How do I add a `CheckBox` to the `AlertDialog` that will make the app no longer show the `AlertDialog` when the user opens the app?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You have to use the method `setView(View)` on the `AlertDialog.Builder` object. This will put the passed in `View` between the message area and buttons. Simply inflate a `View` with a `CheckBox` and pass that in. Here's an example:

checkbox.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Code in your Activity

```
View checkBoxView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.checkbox, null);
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        // Save to shared preferences
    }
});
checkBox.setText("Text to the right of the check box.");

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(" MY_TEXT");
    builder.setMessage(" MY_TEXT ")
           .setView(checkBoxView)
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=MY_APP_PACKAGE");
                   Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); 
                   startActivity(intent);                          }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           }).show();
```

Comment: I think you need to cast the view returned by findViewById to a CheckBox.  Great answer otherwise.

Comment: Try to avoid using long text with the sample xml layut, the checkbox will be hidden if your text is too long

Comment: Where do you save that xml file?  in layouts or somewhere else? thanks.  oh it says R.louyouts.checkbox.xml... oops. teehee

Comment: @JasonRobinson I know this is kind of old but I am wanting to do a similar thing in my DialogFragment. However, `View checkBoxView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.checkbox, null);` is giving off this error

"Error:(28, 42) error: incompatible types: WifivsDataDialog cannot be converted to Context"

Comment: Now, if only the checkbox would be alligned with the text. I don't want to fiddle around with fixed values...anyone?

Comment: Scrolling is broken for this method. Bottom part is hidden when text is too long.

Answer (score 18):

[image]

The way to make a checkbox list is to use `setMultiChoiceItems` in the `AlertDialog`.

```
// Set up the alert builder
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setTitle("Choose some animals");

// Add a checkbox list
String[] animals = {"horse", "cow", "camel", "sheep", "goat"};
boolean[] checkedItems = {true, false, false, true, false};
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(animals, checkedItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
        // The user checked or unchecked a box
    }
});

// Add OK and Cancel buttons
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // The user clicked OK
    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

// Create and show the alert dialog
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

Here I hard coded which items in the list were already checked. It is more likely that you would want to keep track of them in an `ArrayList<Integer>`. See the [documentation example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9G2mW.png) for more details. You can also set the checked items to `null` if you always want everything to start unchecked.

For `context`, you can use `this` if you are in an Activity.

My fuller answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43532478/3681880).

#### Kotlin version

```
// Set up the alert builder
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
builder.setTitle("Choose some animals")

// Add a checkbox list
val animals = arrayOf("horse", "cow", "camel", "sheep", "goat")
val checkedItems = booleanArrayOf(true, false, false, true, false)
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(animals, checkedItems) { dialog, which, isChecked ->
    // The user checked or unchecked a box
}

// Add OK and Cancel buttons
builder.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, which ->
    // The user clicked OK
}
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)

// Create and show the alert dialog
val dialog = builder.create()
dialog.show()
```

Comment: Does not work with builder.setMessage("Some Message");

Comment: This looked good at first, but you can't use "setMessage" anymore. You can, but it will delete the checkboxes. So if you need a dialog with text and checkbox this won't work. The user uses setMessage in his question ...

Answer (score 6):

You could use a multichoicelist with only one item:

```
final boolean[] checked = new boolean[] {false};
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(new String[]{"Remember decision"}, checked, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i, boolean b) {
                   checked[i] = b;
               }
           });
```

Then in the `OnClick()` of an alert dialog button you can check the value of `checked[0]`and save that value in your app's `Sharedpreferences`:

```
builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                       if(checked[0]){
                           SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                           editor.putBoolean("preferences_never_buy_pro", true);
                           editor.apply();
                       }
                       dialog.cancel();

                   }
               });
```

With this preference you can decide whether the dialog should be shown again in the future.

Comment: Works fine until you add `builder.setMessage(...)`, unfortunatelly

Comment: Yes if you're calling setMessage too on the dialog builder. This answer will not work. The only solution is using setView

Answer (score 2):

First you need to define a layout that contains the message and checkbox for disabling the alert on subsequent views.  Then instead of calling `builder.setMessage`, you'll call:

```
builder.setView(myAlertViewWithDisablingCheckbox);
```

Then when the user clicks on the alert dialog button, you'll have to check to see if that checkbox has been checked, and save that preference in your app's `SharedPreferences`.  Then you can use that preference to determine if this alert dialog should be shown to the user again.