# Add a link to a button on an AlertDialog that shows when the app starts

Tags: java, android

I have an Android app, I need to add to it an `AlertDialog` that shows when the app starts. Also, I need to add to the `AlertDialog` a button (like: visit website), when the user click that button, it will open the link and browse it in the browser or anything else.

How I can do that?!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to add an `AlertDialog` to your `onCreate()` method in your `Activity`.
After then You have to add a button to that `AlertDialog`.
There are three types of button in `AlertDialog`.

1. Positive
2. Negative
3. Neutral

Use any one of them.

Then when the button clicked you need to go to the website url, in some browser in the android device.

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.your-web-site-url.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Try this:

```
final Context context = this;
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

// set title
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

// set dialog message
alertDialogBuilder
    .setMessage("Click to visit website!")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Go to web site",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            // if this button is clicked

              Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.your-web-site-url.com"));
              startActivity(browserIntent);

        }
    }));

// create alert dialog
AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

// show it
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Thanks! your answer helped me. Can I add a check box (like: Do not show this again)?! If I can, what I need for it?!

Comment: Welcome. Yes you can add a check box or anything you want. just create a layout add a check box in that layout, and then add the check box to the AlertDialog using setView(your_check_box_view). for example see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763643/how-to-add-a-check-box-to-an-alert-dialog

Comment: How I can save the check box to shared preferences if the user check it?! Thanks, your answer was helpful.

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example

Answer (score 2):

Use an `AlertDialog.Builder` in your activities `onCreate()` method. You can use `setPositiveButton()` and launch your website in an intent, or webview when the user clicks it.

For example

```
    new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
        .setMessage("Launch Website")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Hide the dialog
                dialog.dismiss(); 

                // Launch the website
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://google.com"));

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        })
        .show();
```

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html