# How to prevent menu from disappearing on item click in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-menu

I have a menu in which all items have a checkbox.
So it is like a multichoice menu.
I don't want the menu to close when an item is clicked.
I only want to close the menu on back press.
But I can't figure out how to do it?

This is the code:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when(item.itemId) {
        R.id.my_item -> {
            // toggle    
        }
    }

    // something to do here?
    // changing return value to true or false doesn't help
    return false
}
```

Comment: A similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52176838/how-to-hold-the-overflow-menu-after-i-click-it/52177919#52177919). I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

That implementation is hidden under native Android menu management and you get only callback of selected menu item.
It would be better to move all choose items to AlertDialog ([There is simple example I have just googled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56466222/3816129) and have only one menu item which starts showing that AlertDialog

Comment: Yes, `AlertDialog` is an option but I don't want to do that, I just asked the question out of curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to wrap your `menu items` inside `group` tag. Refer code below :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="all">
        <item android:id="@+id/item1"
              android:titleCondensed="Options"
              android:title="Title 1"
              android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences">
        </item>
        <item android:id="@+id/item2"
              android:titleCondensed="Persist"
              android:title="Title 2"
              android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
              android:checkable="true">
        </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

Follow link to know more about [`checkable menu items`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#checkable)

Comment: I already have my menu items being wrapped inside group tag. That doesn't prevent the menu from being closed on item click.

Comment: Have you added  --> . android:checkableBehavior="all" ?

Comment: Yes, I have. As far as I know, `checkableBehaviour="all"` doesn't make any difference "visually" for a group, but `checkableBehaviour="single"` makes the group as a radio group.